# Cannot pull data from a SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new at Java and attempting to build a companion app for a video game that my friends and I play (first app!). With this app, I've built a SQLite database with several tables and attempting to call this, query it, and display this data into a table.

**My Question:** *Edited*

> I created an external SQLite database and copied this to my /assets/databases/ folder. While researching I've found that most people state you have to copy this to the /data/data/Package/databases location to actually use it.
>
> When attempting to access my data, I'm received a "table does not exist" error **ONLY** if I tell it to grab data. If I remove the section calling my data, the app loads fine and moves to activities fine, but is useless if I can't pull my data.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial, PID: 17209
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial/info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial.Anjanath}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: lrgmonsters (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT monstername, element, ailments, weakness, resistances, locations FROM lrgmonsters WHERE MonsterName = 'Anjanath'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: lrgmonsters (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT monstername, element, ailments, weakness, resistances, locations FROM lrgmonsters WHERE MonsterName = 'Anjanath'
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Now, before anyone brings it up, I have scoured the internet. I've read so many blogs and threads and such and it BLOWS my mind the amount of hoops I've had to go through to get a SQLite DB to work in an application.

I've ready through this: ["Using your own SQLite database in Android applications"](https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

And that's what I've been trying to use to 'copy' my SQLite database internally so I can then use it in the app to query my data from.

Below are my items:

**TestDataHelper.java**

```
package info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class TestDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Setting our SQL KEYS
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MONSTERNAME = "monstername";
public static final String KEY_ELEMENT = "element";
public static final String KEY_AILMENTS = "ailments";
public static final String KEY_WEAKNESS = "weakness";
public static final String KEY_RESISTANCES = "resistances";
public static final String KEY_LOCATIONS = "locations";

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "MHWResearchData.db";
private static String DB_TABLE_NAME = "large_monsters";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
private TestDataHelper testhelper;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 *
 * @param context
 */

public String gettestData(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_MONSTERNAME, KEY_ELEMENT, KEY_AILMENTS, KEY_WEAKNESS, KEY_RESISTANCES, KEY_LOCATIONS};
    //Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM large_monsters WHERE monstername = 'Anjanath'",null);
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, columns, KEY_MONSTERNAME, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iMonsterName = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONSTERNAME);
    int iElement = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ELEMENT);
    int iAilments = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_AILMENTS);
    int iWeakness = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEAKNESS);
    int iResistances = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_RESISTANCES);
    int iLocations = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = result + cursor.getString(iMonsterName) + "  "
                + cursor.getString(iElement) + "  "
                + cursor.getString(iAilments) + "  "
                + cursor.getString(iWeakness) + "  "
                + cursor.getString(iResistances) + "  "
                + cursor.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public TestDataHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        //database does't exist yet.

    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 */

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

**Anjanath.java**  *Where my data grab is occurring*

```
package info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Anjanath extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anjanath);

    TestDataHelper myDbHelper = new TestDataHelper(null);
    myDbHelper = new TestDataHelper(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDatabase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }
    try {
        TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLInfo);
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        String newData = myDbHelper.gettestData();
        myDbHelper.close();
        tvv.setText(newData);

    }catch(SQLiteException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
 }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button anjabtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    anjabtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anjabtn);
    anjabtn.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View myview) {
    switch (myview.getId()) {
        case R.id.anjabtn:

            boolean testItem = true;
            try {
                Intent anjIntent = new Intent("info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial.ANJANATH");
                startActivity(anjIntent);

            }catch(Exception excep) {
                testItem = false;
            }finally {
                if (testItem) {
                    Dialog dworks = new Dialog(this);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    dworks.setContentView(tv);
                    dworks.show();
                }else {
                    Dialog dfails = new Dialog(this);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Failure");
                    dfails.setContentView(tv);
                    dfails.show();
                }

            }

            break;
    }


 }
}
```

**Anjanath XML if anyone is curious and wants to help with how I'd sort each SQLite column to each column**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="info.ndakgamers.monsterdatabasetrial.Anjanath">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/anjaBanner"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/anjanath_render" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblMonsterNames"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Monster Names"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblElement"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Element"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblAilments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ailments"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblWeakness"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Weakness"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblResistances"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Resistances"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tblLocations"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Locations"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSQLInfo"
                    android:layout_width="361dp"
                    android:layout_height="61dp"
                    android:text="db Data Goes Here"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="12dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="163dp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hard to tell with certainty from information provided but the SQL error indicates a table name of 'lrgmonsters' yet the code appears to reference a table name of 'large_monsters' so something is not consistent in what is presented.  Since it's not possible to know how the DB was created it's difficult to state further.

Comment: delete your working copy of database put a breakpoint on all openDatabase and start debugging. I am not shure if `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()` will create the db if it does not exist so your catch might never be reached. Also copy may fail because the destination file may not be a valid db and is locked

Comment: You should use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate of your Helper is empty! This means you are not creating any tables. You should create queries with a CREATE TABLE statement for each tabels you put in your database, and execute all those queries in your helper's onCreate.

Also, since you've mentioned the hard work it takes to write all this code, I'll suggest you to take a look at Room Persistence Library, it will help you a lot!

Comment: Based on the reference, it looks like OP is trying to open/access an existing SQLite database (created/populated external to the App).

Comment: Hello Gregorio, thanks for the suggestion of Room and the call out. I figured I might need something there but I was being naïve about that article and thinking it would work without the OnCreate and OnUpgrade sections being filled out.

Room looks like it might be what I need. I dislike the thought of copying the database from within the APK to an further internal location just to access it.

I'll test out some edits and get back.

Comment: Andy - you're correct. I've made an external SQLite database. I'm attempting to query that but from everything I've researched it seems with Java, you need to copy it into the app further than just the /assets/databases/ location to the /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases to actually query it...

Comment: Correct - which is what your 'copyDatabase' method is intending to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that you have copied the file in to **/assets/databases/** but are just using the database name, whilst you need to include the databases sub-directory when opening the file. So instead of

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

you would need to use :-

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("databases/" + DB_NAME);
```

Alternately copy the file into the assets folder rather than the databases sub-directory.